# Practicing "Naked Returns" with Recursion in Go. Is the return statement in my ELSE statement incorrect?

Tags: go, recursion, return

Trying a simple recursive function that takes a number, splits it in a certain way, and is only supposed to return it if the split numbers are equal to each other.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func split(sum int) (x, y int) {
    x = sum * 4 / 9
    y = sum - x

    if y == x || sum > 200 {
        return
    } else {
        split(sum+1)
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(split(10))
}
```

The output for `fmt.Println(split(10))` is `4 and 6`, which is incorrect since they're not equal to each other. Is this due to the return statement t the end of my ELSE statement? I have a JAVA background so I figured that line would never get hit.

Comment: Okay so I just tried it without the ceiling of `sum > 200` and I got a StackOverflow error. Could that be what's causing it? It gets an error so it just goes back to the next part of the ELSE statement and just returns what doesn't cause an error?

Comment: You're not doing anything with the values returned from the recursive call to `sum()`.

Comment: @Adrian can you clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: @Adrian is saying that `x, y = split(sum+1)` and `split(sum+1)` are different things,  the former does something with `split`'s return values whereas the latter ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

As you are declaring the variables in the function definition with `(x, y int)` performing a return will return the values of `x` and `y` at that point. When you call the split function recursively it will assign a new `x` and `y` for that function call, so changing the values there will not effect the outer scope.

You can fix this by returning the return value of the recursive `split` call, as currently you are ignoring the results by calling it on the line before the return.

However I would note that any input value > 0 will never be equal in this implementation and will return the same value for any input as the `sum > 200` clause triggers.

https://play.golang.org/p/fzuPtqPCxpE

```
package main

import "fmt"

func split(sum int) (int, int) {
    x := sum * 4 / 9
    y := sum - x

    if y == x || sum > 200 {
        return
    } else {
        return split(sum + 1)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(split(10))
}
```

Comment: Better if the `int, int` was `x, y int `and the `:=` was `=` as per the original question?